# Parse.com Query on Child Object Key within an Array of Objects Column

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

A Parse class has a column labeled BoxData and is an Array type.  Each value for that BoxData column is an array of objects.

```
BoxData (Array)
BoxData value1 = [{"boxID":"1","boxWeight":"12kg"},{"boxID":"4","boxWeight":"12kg"}]
BoxData value2 = [{"boxID":"12","boxWeight":"12kg"},{"boxID":"24","boxWeight":"12kg"}]
BoxData value3 = [{"boxID":"123","boxWeight":"12kg"},{"boxID":"124","boxWeight":"12kg"}]
```

equalTo("BoxData.boxID","124") does not work.

How should a Parse Javascript SDK query be written with constraints if trying to return all rows where boxID=124 ?

Comment: That doesn't look like JavaScript

Comment: This is a downside to the "object" data type.  Whether in an array or singularly, you can't specify queries based upon the content of objects.  Idea 1: maybe BoxData can be made a first-class parse object, Idea 2: reduce the query results with some other criteria, then search the box data arrays in app code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use dot notation with Array or Dictionary types. This feature can only be used with Pointer types.

https://parse.com/questions/includekey-dot-notation-doesnt-work-on-arrays

Comment: Appreciate the answer. It would be useful if it worked.