# Parse.com - query an object key in an array

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am looking to query on an array of objects using the Parse Javascript SDK, finding matches on one of these objects' properties based on an array of values I provide.

To explain: I have a Parse object containing an array column. This array in an array of non-Parse objects. As an example, this is the type of data I store:

```
{ objectId: 'xyxyxyxyx',
  tags: [
    {"name" : "love", "auto" : true},
    {"name" : "war", "auto" : false}
  ]
}
```

I wish to query whether the tags property matches with an array of tag names I pass in. To demonstrate, here is a pseudo-code example:

```js
var query = new Parse.Query('Songs');
query.containedIn('tags.name', ['love', 'war']);
query.find()
```

I find that this query works when I run parse-server locally. However, when I use the Parse API, I get the following error:

```
{"code":102,"message":"Dot notation can only be used on objects"}
```

Unfortunately, due to the constraints of the client, we cannot migrate to using parse-server just yet.

Does anyone know if there is a way to query on object keys using the existing remotely hosted Parse API.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510945/parse-com-query-on-child-object-key-within-an-array-of-objects-column?rq=1 - sadly it seems like this isn't possible. 

But worth noting that this seems to work on the new open source parse-server